# Why does my program crash when I enter sentinel value?

Tags: c++, variable-assignment

My program runs basically fine until i decide to input the sentinel value to stop the program, and it displays an error 
"Exception thrown at 0x00B474AD in Project 4.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00B52FF9.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued."
I'm trying to figure out what is causing this to bug out, could it be that row is initialized to 0 so it is always true?

here is the code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

#include "C:\Users\barta\OneDrive\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Project 4\Project 4\array.h"

void displayPlane(char msg[], char[ROW][COL]);
void getData(int &, char &);

int main()
{
    int row = 0;
    char seat;

    while (row != -1)
    {

        displayPlane("\tChesapeaake Airlines", layout);
        cout << endl;
        getData(row, seat);
        cout << endl;
        int COL = seat - 'A';
        if (layout[row - 1][COL] == 'X')
        {
            cout << "Sorry this seat is take" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            layout[row - 1][COL] = 'X';
        }

    }

    cout << "Have a nice day! " << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
void displayPlane(char msg[] , char[ROW][COL])
{
    cout <<msg << endl;
    for (int r = 0; r < ROW; r++)
    { cout << endl;
    cout << setw(4) << r + 1;
        for (int c = 0; c < COL; c++)
        {
            cout << setw(4) << layout[r][c];
        }
    }
}
void getData(int& row, char& seat)
{

    cout << "Enter row <-1 to stop>  ";
    cin >> row;
    cout << "Enter your prefered seat  ";
    cin >> seat;
    seat = toupper(seat);
}
```

and here is the header file

```
//arrays for airline problem

const int ROW = 9;
const int COL = 4;
const int CTR = 3;

//initial seats in the plane
    char layout[ROW][COL] = {  { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' },
                            { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' }};

    int classCtr[CTR] = {0,0,0};

    string classes[] = {"First Class", "Business Class", "Coach"};

    double fare [] = {500, 300, 100};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have determined -1 to be your sentinel value and you even kindly print this information:

```
cout << "Enter row <-1 to stop>  ";
cin >> row;
```

you haven't told the program that there's anything special about -1.

So, row is now equal to -1. The program continues.

```
cout << "Enter your prefered seat  ";
cin >> seat;
seat = toupper(seat);
```

and then we return to main. Again, you've not told the program to worry about the value of row, which is -1. So now you execute:

```
    cout << endl;
    int COL = seat - 'A';
    if (layout[row - 1][COL] == 'X')
```

Question: If `row` is -1, which element of `layout` do you access?

If -1 is a sentinel value, you need to write code to enforce this; the while condition is only tested at the start of each loop iteration, it is not a supervisory condition.

First:

```
void getData(int& row, char& seat)
{
    cout << "Enter row <-1 to stop>  ";
    cin >> row;
    if (row == -1)
        return;
    cout << "Enter your prefered seat  ";
    cin >> seat;
    seat = toupper(seat);
}
```

secondly in main:

```
cout << endl;
getData(row, seat);
if (row == -1)
    break;
cout << endl;
int COL = seat - 'A';
```

personally, I would change "getData" to return a bool indicating whether data was fetched or not, and assume that when it returns `false` the user entered the sentinel value - that way I don't have to export knowledge of what that is outside the function.

```
bool getData(int& row, char& seat)
{
    cout << "Enter row <-1 to stop>  ";
    cin >> row;
    if (row == -1)
        return false;
    cout << "Enter your preferred seat  ";
    cin >> seat;
    seat = toupper(seat);
    return true;
}
```

and in main:

```
cout << endl;
if (getData(row, seat) == false) // or just if (!getData(row, seat))
    break;
cout << endl;
int COL = seat - 'A';
```

and change the `while` loop to

```
for (;;)  // infinite loop
{
    ...
```

Comment: I understand your logic but my professor wants the function to be void so idk if that will work

Comment: Stick with the first half of the answer then, i.e. `return;` after detecting the sentinel immediately after the user inputs it.

Comment: Thanks man that did the trick! Basically i over looked the part of the sentinel value not being determined

Answer (score 0):

```
getData(row, seat);
cout << endl;
int COL = seat - 'A';
if (layout[row - 1][COL] == 'X')
```

If you enter -1, you're accessing

```
layout[-2]
```

Comment: So then would i change 1- row?

Comment: Your logic is wrong.  If you enter the sentinel value, you're done - you should be skipping over the part where you manipulate the set of seats that are taken.

Comment: Hmmmmm thats were i a stumped